# I have to redesign a website in joomla from HTML.Basically the HTML site is in 2 lanugage English and French

Tags: joomla1.5

I have to redesign a website in joomla from HTML.Basically the HTML site is in 2 lanugage English and French.Now the problem is that there is different menus and block in both the language sites.If the menus and rest of design is same then i can easily do using Joomfish..please tell me how i can mange this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question really comes down to a choice between two options:

(1) Having a multi-lingual site. This type of site is manually coded to contain duplicate menu items and articles, each written "by hand" in the native language. If your site is one where the language contains nuances that would be missed by auto-translation software like JoomFish, then you better go this route. There is more planning involved for such a site.

(2) Having a single language site that can be translated to another language using a translator like JoomFish (or a dozen others). If the language in your project is not specifically nuanced, you might consider this route, as it will be FAR easier to build. Translation software like JoomFish does a pretty good job. I even use the translation built into CometChat for some of my clients, and they're pretty happy with the results. The translations aren't 100% perfect, but most web viewers understand this nowadays.

You might consider reading this article:
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_multi-language_support

And then look at this directory:
http://extensions.joomla.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=listcats&cat_id=1838&Itemid=35